# Can't get the token in Postman whenever I use middleware in my private routes

Tags: node.js, header, authorization, token, postman

I am now able to successfully set the authorization header to be a token in my `/login` router. However, I am having difficulty getting Postman to set the token as a header whenever I test my private routes.

Here is when I run the login router. It successfully sets the header to be the user's token that is generated.

[image]

Despite filling out the header key-form with the token I got from the other login route, Postman doesn't correctly run the code after sending the request because Postman doesn't have a token.

[image]

The lack of a token in Postman can be seen in the lower part where my custom header "x-auth" and the token value are nowhere to be seen
[image]

Here is the code that is involved for reference:

The middleware I am using:

```
exports.verifyOrdinaryUser = function (req, res, next) {
    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token

    let token =  req.header('x-auth');

    // decode token
    if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, config.secretKey, function (req, res, next) {
            if (err) {
                let err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
                err.status = 401;
                return next(err);
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.user = user;
                req.token = token;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        let err = new Error('No token provided!');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }
};
```

And here is the router:

```
router.post('/addrecipe', authentication.verifyOrdinaryUser, (req, res) => {

            Recipe.create({
                name: req.body.name,
                description: req.body.description,
                steps: req.body.steps,
                ingredients: req.body.ingredients,
                category: req.body.category,
                postedBy: req.user.id,
                postersCreationDate: req.user.creationDate,
                postersName: req.user.username
            }, (err, recipe) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);

                res.json(recipe);

            });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To set authentication token in Postman, go to `Authorization` tab and select `OAuth 2.0` as `Type`. You can find a button to get new token there where you can enter your credentials to receive a token which you can set for later requests.

https://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/concepts/postman/postman.html

To set `Content-Type` set `Accept: application/json` in `Headers` instead of `Content-Type: application/json`